# UK pound sign being stripped from a form

Tags: php, encoding

I have a forum and I am have issue where when a post is made including a £ (pound) sign it will not display the sign and will strip it?

I have submitted the form, and made sure that no functions get hold of it after its submitted and then echo'ed the sign stright from $_POST and it will still not display the sign. It dosnt seem to be anything that would do this, unless its set with the encoding on the form?

forum is FluxBB but also drawing blanks there too. issue can be tested here http://www.drivertrainingtoday.co.uk/test.php

code for that page is

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    Age: <input type="text" name="age">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php chr(26); ?>

Welcome <?php echo utf8_decode($_POST["fname"]); ?>!
<br />
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.
```

Comment: Why are you using `utf8_decode`? If you have utf-8... you are converting it to iso8859 here..

Comment: I was just testing a few different functions to see if it would show. No luck though.

Comment: Well, several things wrong you need to fix. (1) your webserver sends `Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`, so no utf-8 (2) your html is invalid, don't assume any outcome significant from your test-case until it is.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I have changed the server to send utf-8 and still not joy. Please understand that the link provided is just to prove that it does not work, this is not the actual form I am using. The form I am using is a forum software which i have tested is all valid.